# Encoding problems in ASP when using English and Chinese characters

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, asp-classic, httpresponse

I am having problems with encoding Chinese in an ASP site. The file formats are:

- translations.txt - UTF-8 (to store my translations)
- test.asp - UTF-8 - (to render the page)

test.asp is reading translations.txt that contains the following data:

```
Help|ZH|帮助 
Home|ZH|首页
```

The test.asp splits on the pipe delimiter and if the user contains a cookie with ZH, it will display this translation, else it will just revert back to the Key value.

Now, I have tried the following things, which have not worked:

1. Add a meta tag

   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>`
2. Set the `Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"`
3. Set the `Response.ContentType = "text/html"`
4. Set the Session.CodePage (and Response) to both 65001 (UTF-8)
5. I have confirmed that the text in `translations.txt` is definitely in UTF-8 and has **no byte order mark**
6. The browser is picking up that the page is Unicode UTF-8, but the page is displaying gobbledegook.
7. The `Scripting.OpenTextFile(<file>,<create>,<iomode>,<encoding>)` method returns the same incorrect text regardless of the Encoding parameter.

Here is a sample of what I want to be displayed in China (ZH):

- 首页
- 帮助

But the following is displayed:

- é¦–é¡µ
- å¸®åŠ©

This occurs all tested browsers - Google Chrome, IE 7/8, and Firefox 4. The font definitely has a Chinese branch of glyphs. Also, I do have Eastern languages installed.

--

I have tried pasting in the original value into the HTML, which did work (but note this is a hard coded value).

- 首页
- é¦–é¡µ

However, this is odd.

首页 --(in hex)--> E9 A6 96 E9 A1 --(as chars)--> é¦–é¡µ

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to read the UTF-8 file, you'll probably need to use the [`ADODB.Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032%28VS.85%29.aspx) object.  I don't claim to be an expert on character encoding, but this test worked for me:

test.txt (saved as UTF-8 without BOM):

> 首页
>   帮助

test.vbs

```
Option Explicit

Const adTypeText = 2
Const adReadLine = -2

Dim stream : Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type = adTypeText
stream.Charset = "UTF-8"
stream.LoadFromFile "test.txt"

Do Until stream.EOS
    WScript.Echo stream.ReadText(adReadLine)
Loop

stream.Close
```

Comment: This works but watchout for memory usage if text.txt is large and be sure to `Close` the stream, ADODB.Streams can get a bit funky if you don't close them.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever part of the process is reading the `translations.txt` file does not seem to understand that the file is in UTF-8. It looks like it is reading it in as some other encoding. You should specify encoding in whatever process is opening and reading that file. This will be different from the encoding of your web page.

Inserting the byte order mark at the beginning of that file may also be a solution.

Comment: That would be the Encoding of -1 (UTF-8) in the OpenTextFile() method. The problem is ASP doesn't like byte order marks in files as it includes the  binary marker in the data. However, even if this was skipped, the text is still read incorrectly from the file, exactly like I presented above - é¦–é¡µ. It is a pain :-(

Comment: @Dominic Zukiewicz - I don't know if this will work, but try it with 1 instead of -1.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then try using UTF-16LE (in Windows vernacular "Unicode") as the encoding.

Comment: @Dominic: `Scripting.OpenTextFile` doesn't understand UTF-8 at all.  In addition UTF-8 is not a good choice for these characters, straight forward 2 byte Unicode would be better and is understood by OpenTextFile.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I have just converted the file to UTF-16 LE and it is now interpreting a single character as a complete line. Therefore "Home" is read as 4 lines - 'H','o','m','e'. It must think that nulls are line separators.

Comment: @Dominic: I've now added my own answer, you need to look at the format parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`Scripting.OpenTextFile` does not understand UTF-8 at all.  It can only read the current OEM encoding or Unicode.  As you can see from the number of bytes being used for some character sets UTF-8 is quite inefficient.  I would recommend Unicode for this sort of data.

You should save the file as Unicode (in Windows parlance) and then open with:

```
Dim stream : Set stream = Scripting.OpenTextFile(yourFilePath, 1, false, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the script below at the top of your page

```
Response.CodePage=65001
Response.CharSet="UTF-8"
```